# Restore session after restart in JBoss

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, jboss

Can I somehow restore the session on JBoss after restart? I want to use it on my development machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in the [documentation](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/DisableSessionPersistence):

> Since JBoss-3.2.6RC1:
>
> The default tomcat session manager will persist sessions. This can
>   lead to problems when restarting jboss or redeploying a war if the
>   session contains non-serializable data.
>
> To disable session persistence, you create a WEB-INF/context.xml with
>   a Manager element that sets the pathname to an empty value:

```
<Context>
   <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager"
      pathname="" ></Manager>
</Context>
```

> JBoss-3.2.5 and earlier do not read the WEB-INF/context.xml file.
>
> JBoss 4.0.3 has this disabled by default.  See
>   /jboss-4.0.3/server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat55.sar/context.xml

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

All servlet containers will try to keep the session alive between server restarts. But all session objects must be serializable in order for this to work.