# Restarts server getting logged out

Tags: java, database

I am using Jboss server. Whenever trying to restart server my application is getting logged out. I wont allow user to logout until Log off the applicaion. How to manage this thing. Like gmail i need to do.

Comment: Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862969/restore-session-after-restart-in-jboss

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it by HA Web Sessions via Database Persistence.**
The basic use case we hear for this is environments where sessions need to be available to AS instances located across a WAN. JBoss Cache/JGroups clusters can span a WAN but often users find it impractical to configure their cluster(s) in that way. However, their IT infrastructure already supports making RDBMS data accessible across the WAN. So, persisting sessions to the DB makes them available across the WAN.
For more details visit [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HAWebSessionsViaDatabasePersistence)